# In Lua, what is #INF and #IND?

Tags: c, floating-point, lua, floating-point-conversion

I'm fairly new to Lua.  While testing I discovered `#INF`/`#IND`.  However, I can't find a good reference that explains it.

What are `#INF`, `#IND`, and similar (such as negatives) and how do you generate and use them?

Comment: `1/0`, `-1/0` and `0/0`

Comment: Your Lua build must be using a floating-point type for Lua's `number` type. (The default Lua build uses the C `double` type.) See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#INF` is infinite, `#IND` is NaN. Give it a test:

```
print(1/0)
print(0/0)
```

Output on my Windows machine:

```
1.#INF
-1.#IND
```

As there's no standard representation for these in ANSI C, you may get different result. For instance:

```
inf
-nan
```

Comment: `-1.#IND` is a particular NaN pattern known as `INDEFINITE`. The bit pattern for the double-precision version is `0xfff800000000000`.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding @YuHao already good answer.

Lua does little when converting a number to a string, since it heavily relies on the underlying C library implementation. In fact Lua [`print` implementation](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_print) calls Lua `tostring` which in turn (after a series of other calls) uses the [`lua_number2str` macro](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/luaconf.h.html#lua_number2str), which is defined in terms of [C `sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Thus in the end you see whatever representation for infinities and NaNs the C implementation uses (this may vary according to which compiler was used to compile Lua and which C runtime your application is linked to).

Answer (score 6):

@YuHao has already answered what the OP has asked: what does `+/-1.#INF` (+-inf) and `-1.#IND` (NaN) mean.
What I want to do here is just to add to the discussion by expanding on how to check them (which I just needed and learned to):

- **inf** (`+/-1.#INF`) are the highest numbers(+/-) Lua can represent, and the Language provides such value(s) through `math.huge`. You can test if a number is +/-INF:

```lua
local function isINF(value)
  return value == math.huge or value == -math.huge
end
```

- **NaN** (`-1.#IND`) is something that can not be handled numerically, *the result of any operation involving it is also Not-a-Number*(*). Long-story-short: if a value is `NaN`, comparing it against itself will (always) be *False*. The function below implements the simplest way for checking if a value is `NaN`:

```lua
local function isNAN(value)
  return value ~= value
end
```

(*): NaN is formally defined in the IEEE754 standard.