# Lua check if a number/value is nan

Tags: lua, nan

I have written a program to print a matrix after some computations and I am getting an output of `nan` for all elements. I want to break a `for` loop as soon as the matrix's first element becomes `nan` to understand the problem. How can I do this? In the terminal, I have printed the matrix `a` containing `nan` as all elements and typed `a[1][1]=="nan"` and `a[{{1},{1}}]=="nan"` both of which return `false`. Why are they not returning `false` and what statement should I use instead?

Comment: `local function isNaN( v ) return type( v ) == "number" and v ~= v end`

Comment: `local function isNaN( v ) return tostring(v) == tostring(0/0) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff -(0/0) results in a different string even though it is still nan thus returning false even though true should be returned. https://ideone.com/YoOljy

Comment: @Rochet2 - Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your test fails because you are comparing a number with a string, `"nan"`.

If you are sure it's a number, the easiest way is:

```
if a[1][1] ~= a[1][1] then
```

because according to IEEE 754, a `nan` value is considered not equal to any value, including itself.

Answer (score 8):

Two solutions:

```
local n = 0/0 -- nan

-- first solution
if ( tostring(n) == "nan" ) then
   print("is nan!!")
end

-- second solution
if (n ~= n) then
   print("is nan!!")
end
```

Comment: Per this question on [Is there a way to detect NaN and -NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280708/1366033), `"nan"` is "*not portable*", presumably because that's the `tostring` output on linux while [windows uses `#IND`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19107302/1366033).  So the safer equation is to repeat the `tostring` of something we know to be NaN (i.e. `0/0`) like this: `tostring(n) == tostring(0/0)`

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
for x = 1, x2 do          -- x2 depends on how big you matrix is.
  for y = 1, y2 do        -- y2 the same as x2
    -- some code depending on how your program works
    if a[x][y] == nan then
      print( "X:" .. x .. ", Y:" .. y )
      break
    end
  end
end
```

PS: (nan == nan) is true

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. The variable "nan" is not defined in Lua, so it will evaluate to (nil). (nil == nil) is indeed true. However, (0/0 == 0/0) is false!

Comment: PS: (nan == nan) is **false**, as it should be.