# How to convert a double to a small string representation without data loss in any lua without external libs?

Tags: serialization, lua, numbers, tostring, number-formatting

I'd like to convert a number to a string using only any Lua version, so that

- ### there is no data loss (necessary!)
- the string representation is as small as possible (8 bytes would be fine) (optional, not necessary)
- ### no external libs are used (necessary!)
- the conversion is as fast as possible (optional, not necessary)

I don't care about

- human readability
- avoiding special characters

I tried the built-in `tonumber` function, but it does not always give correct results:

```
> print((2+256^6)==(1+256^6))
false
> print(tostring(2+256^6)==tostring(1+256^6))
true
```

Comment: floating point numbers are lossy by definition - if you really need to avoid *any* data loss you can't use floats to begin with.

Comment: lua has one number data type - these numbers are doubles - i want to be able to serialize these in order to be able to serializing anything except userdata & threads ...

Comment: can someone post a complete solution?

Comment: SO is not a place where complete solution is given

Comment: where do you get that from? I saw many complete solutions to small problems like mine! I don't think serializing a number is big science. Furthermore, if there are only faulty answers, guys who embed them in their programs get serious problems! They try to serialize a nan and wonder why they get nil when they deserialize the data!

Comment: Your requirement - that you *never* lose precision - is not a small problem. [Revisit your requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573) and you'll have an easier time getting an actionable answer.

Comment: any "double" (IEEE 754, "double precision") can be stored using 8 bytes. the question is how to do that using pure lua only. Any compressing format would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   -- Encoding/decoding without data loss

   local NaN_serialized = {
      [string.format('%.17g',   1/0 )] =  '1/0',
      [string.format('%.17g',  -1/0 )] = '-1/0',
      [string.format('%.17g',   0/0 )] =  '0/0',
      [string.format('%.17g', -(0/0))] =  '-(0/0)'
   }
   -- How to encode:
   str_value = string.format('%.17g', num_value):gsub('^.*', NaN_serialized):gsub(',', '.')

   -- How_to_decode:
   num_value = loadstring("return "..str_value)()
```

Comment: seems to work (at least with the lua i use currently) . pro : very very short solution, kontra : the string representation is pretty large.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use standard Lua libs, try these:

```
x=math.pi

s=string.pack("d",x)
y=string.unpack("d",s)
print(x==y)

s=string.format("%a",x)
y=tonumber(s)
print(x==y)
```

`string.format("%a",x)` is available in Lua 5.2+. `string.pack` is available in Lua 5.3+.

Comment: seems better than tostring! how deserialize? is there a string.format in any lua version?

Comment: Tried it out: yout can't deserialize (-)nans and (-)infs using tonumber, but seems fine for any other.

Comment: Also (out of http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial about string.format) "The options A, a may be available in Lua 5.2 and greater." (it should work with any lua version), string.pack not in my lua at all.

Comment: "string.format("%a",x) is available in Lua 5.2+. string.pack is available in Lua 5.3+." - does not solve the question. also support nans, infs and their negative versions.

Answer (score 1):

This includes a number_to_str and a number_from_str function :

https://github.com/bakpakin/binser/blob/master/binser.lua

Apparantly, they are capable of more than Lua's builtin tonumber...

Comment: print(number_from_str(number_to_str(-(0/0)),1) == -(0/0)) gives false. this does not save the difference between nan and -nan, also, this is quite a lot code. If you forked it and made a version that worked it would be fine.

Comment: if NaNs are not handled, you could easily add it yourself.

Comment: yes, but i don't want to check pages of code for further errors, if you do and you find nothing your solution is fine.

Comment: i havent got time to do so

Comment: As for your `(-0/0)==(-0/0)` test, there is no "minus nan" https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759548/4687565

Comment: Of course there is! print(0/0) gives -nan, print(-(0/0)) gives nan. (Lua 5.2.4)

Comment: Furthermore, print(number_from_str(number_to_str(-(0/0)),1)) gives -nan, print(-(0/0)) gives nan! (test shown earlier is invalid) (Lua 5.2.4) Dimitry, are you the guy who made faulty binser?