# Is there a way to detect NaN and -NaN?

Tags: lua, numbers, nan

I want to save lua number to string and handle `NaN` case correctly.

Detecting any NaN is easy, `x ~= x`.

However, only one way which I've found to detect is it `NaN` or `-NaN` is to use `tostring(x) == 'nan'`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How do you get -NaN ?

Comment: @lhf `0/0` is `-nan`, `-(0/0)` is `nan` (as `tostring` says).

Comment: `string.pack(">d", your_NaN):byte() > 127`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff there is no function `string.pack`.

Comment: @val - This function is from Lua 5.3.  To get relevant answer, please mark your question with a tag corresponding to your Lua version.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It is hard, code should be compatible with lua 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than two NaNs exist (actually, there are `2^52-1` NaNs according to IEEE-754).
Their `tostring`-ed representations are platform-dependent.
This is an example how to get three different NaNs (I'm using Lua 5.3 built with Visual Studio):

```
n = string.unpack(">d", string.pack(">d", 0/0):sub(1, -2).."@")
print(0/0, -(0/0), n) -->  -1.#IND   1.#QNAN   -1.#QNAN
```

So, it would be more correct to not distinguish between different variants of NaN.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `tostring(x) == 'nan'`, which is not portable, you can do the comparison with the actual `tostring` call: `tostring(x) == tostring(0/0)` or `tostring(x) == tostring(-(0/0))` depending on what you need. If you need to do multiple comparisons, you can save the result of `tostring` and reuse it.